# I'd like to access my LAN apps from my android phone for apps development

Tags: android, networking, android-studio

I have a set of webservices that are only accessible from within my work computer's network.

I am developing an android app that uses those web services. Is there a way to be able to run the app on my android device and still be able to access those urls?

--

How to enable my phone to access local lan? there is no wifi..

Comment: Short answer to short question: yes as long as you're in the same network with proper permissions. But you'll have to provide more information such as how those web services are invoked if you want a more precise answer.

Comment: use a VPN.  your work network would need to accept a vpn connection from the device- allowing the device to be connected to the LAN